# Kubernetes Ingress log : unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Here is the error:

```
E0925 06:21:54.834031       5 backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage.
```

I understood the problem could not find some decent document to resolve the issue, If i need to change the parameters where should i change.
It would be great if someone helps me out.

Comment: are your cert and key valid?

Comment: Yeah both are valid

Comment: System was running fine since a year, looks like SSL certificate going to expire in a month and kubernetes trying to create a certificate itself. This is where i am facing this issue. Cluster was created by somebody else and i am still new to complex cluster management.

Comment: Try using `--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false`, if that won't woke we will need more details from you to locate an issue.

Comment: well i added --enable-ssl-chain-completion=false in ingress config, looks like its not working.

Comment: @Manjunathg, `--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false` is an `Ingress` controller's option. You need to add it as the container arg in your `Deployment`. FYI